# for which values an Ellipsoid cut the axis

Tags: calculus

I got the general formula of an Ellipsoid
$$\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-\beta)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(z-\gamma)^2}{c^2}=1$$

I understand that $(\alpha, \beta,\gamma)$ are the center of the Ellipsoid but when do the Ellipsoid cut the axis, for example the x-axis?
Does $x=\alpha$ or $a=0$?

Comment: Set $y=z=0$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas does not it turn to a line on the x-axis?

Comment: I now noticed that you asked for **when**, not **where**. Same procedure as in my comment above, and the answer by rotaiva. Except of course we want the equation to have a solution, meaning $(x-\alpha)^2\ge 0$. The condition then is $\frac{\beta^2}{b^2}+\frac{\gamma^2}{c^2}\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsoid will cut the $x$-axis when $y=0,z=0$.

Similarly, it cuts the $y$-axis when $x=0,z=0$

And so on.

Comment: both of $y$ and $z$ need to be $0$?

Comment: Yes, both $y$ and $z$ need to be 0 and then you can solve for $x$ to find the $x-axis$ intercepts of the ellipsoid.